# php json_encode not working on arrays partially

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP code which needs to encode DB table datas into json.
So I used json_encode().

I use the tables given here - http://www.geekality.net/2011/08/21/country-names-continent-names-and-iso-3166-codes-for-mysql/

The behavious of this code seems to be different for different inputs.

The query - `$query = "SELECT * FROM countries ";` doesn't return any json values.
 
The query -`$query = "SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='AS'";` returns json values correctly. 
whereas,`$query = "SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='EU'";` also does't return anything.

Similarily 'NA','AF' did not work and others work perfect.

I'm weird of this behaviour of PHP's json_encode.

This is my code.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxxx','joomla30');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='EU'") or die (mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $orders[] = array(
          'CountryCode' => $row['code'],
          'CountryName' => $row['name']
          );
  }
//print_r($orders);

echo json_encode($orders);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Until the previous line of json_encode, the datas are carried. So I think its json encode problem.

I tried to know about it using `print_r($orders);`.
I got the following output from it.

If I try for 'EU', i get this array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AD [CountryName] => Andorra ) 
[1] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AL [CountryName] => Albania ) 
[2] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AT [CountryName] => Austria ) 
[3] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AX [CountryName] => Åland Islands )...
```

If I try for 'AS', i get this array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AE [CountryName] => United Arab Emirates ) 
[1] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AF [CountryName] => Afghanistan) 
[2] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AM [CountryName] => Armenia) 
[3] => Array ( [CountryCode] => AZ [CountryName] => Azerbaijan)...
```

Both the arrays looks alike right...
But Json_encode works only on 'AS' and not for 'EU'.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?
If so, pls tell me..

Comment: I guess, the Problem is the "Åland Islands" because json_encode has problems with the "Å" for being a weird unicode.
Try setting your mysql_connection to UTF-8

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should make sure that every component of your web application uses UTF-8. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/491494) from another question will tell you how to do this. If you [read this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) from RFC4627:

> Encoding: JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

The json_encode function requires all incoming data to be UTF-8 encoded. That's why strings such as `Åland Islands` are probably causing you problems.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response within 2 minutes.. 
I added `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');`
It worked perfect...

Answer (score 15):

Just a random guess here: `json_encode` requires all data you feed in to be *UTF-8 encoded* and it will fail otherwise. These countries where it fails, you likely have data which contains non-ASCII characters. Pure ASCII happens to be compatible with UTF-8, non-ASCII characters you need to take special care of. See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for how to get UTF-8 encoded data out of your database (use [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset)).

Comment: Thanks, i just added the following code `$db->set_charset("utf8");` in my prepared statement and work perfectly