# Identical Array -> JSON code doesn't work

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to convert an Array to JSON in PHP I have two identical pieces of code except for them referencing to different databases and data. could someone help me? 
The code that works:

```
    get_all_products.php
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp product array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["pname"] = $row["pname"];
        $product["pprice"] = $row["pprice"];
        $product["pamount"] = $row["pamount"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The one that doesn't work:

```
    post2.php
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the users
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all users from users table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // users node
    $response["users"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $user = array();
        $user["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $user["name"] = $row["name"];
        $user["balance"] = $row["balance"];
        $user["pin"] = $row["pin"];

        // push single user into final response array
        array_push($response["users"], $user);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no users found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No users found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I Asked my teacher too but he didn't know the answer either.

Comment: Is there any data in the table? Please post the content of the table. Have you tried executing the query on the server?

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ you say?

Comment: What exactly `not work`? You have errors? Unexpected results? Or what?

Comment: There is data in the table namely and the array can be read out and displayed. But when i tried to covert it into JSON code it just doesn't do it in the second one. Executing the query on the server worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Are data in $response array from second table in UTF-8? Found similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999665/php-json-encode-not-working-on-arrays-partially

Comment: I found the answer, thanks guys. apparently unicode can't read accents on letters. So I changed all table entries so that the names don't contain accents anymore.